# Android Studio doesn't show gradle.properties file

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Since I created a global gradle configuration in %USER_HOME%/.gradle/gradle.properties, my project in android studio doesn't show me the local gradle.properties file anymore.

Instead I see a "Resource Bundle 'gradle'" which contains only the global file.
[image]

Can anyone guide me how to get the local file back in the view?
I am using latest Android Studio 3.2

Comment: bug report at IssueTracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77497027

Comment: Thanks for this. starred it.